# jquery autocomplete not working on cloned rows dynamic formset django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, autocomplete

I am using Jquery autocomplete and is working fine in the first row. the dynamically added rows are not having autocomplete. I am new here.

Here is the code for dynamic formset:

```
function addForm(btn, prefix) {
    var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
    var row = $('.dynamic-form:first').clone();
    $(row).removeAttr('id').insertBefore($('.dynamic-form:last')).children('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    $(row).children().not(':last').children().each(function() {
        updateElementIndex(this, prefix, formCount);
        $(this).val('');
    });

    $(row).find('.delete-row').click(function() {
        deleteForm(this, prefix);
    });

    $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(formCount + 1);
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the code for initializing the autocomplete:

```
$('.autocomplete).each(function() {
    var datacontent = $("#"+this.id).attr('data-content');
    $("#"+this.id).autocomplete({
        source: datacontent, // json format
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#"+this.id+"_id").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#"+this.id).val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            if ($("#"+this.id).val().length == 0) {
                $("#"+this.id+"_id").val('');
            }            
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
var row = $('.dynamic-form:first').clone(true);
```

instead of

```
var row = $('.dynamic-form:first').clone();
```

by setting `true` in `clone()` it clones with event handlers.

And You can use event handler instead of `each` function

```
$('.autocomplete').on("click",function() {
    var datacontent = $("#"+this.id).attr('data-content');
    $("#"+this.id).autocomplete({
        source: datacontent, // json format
        select: function(event, ui) {
           $("#"+this.id+"_id").val(ui.item.value);
           $("#"+this.id).val(ui.item.label);
           return false;
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            if ($("#"+this.id).val().length == 0) {
                $("#"+this.id+"_id").val('');
            }            
        }
    });
});
```

you can change `click` according to your requirement.
`each` function works on already generated dom elements but when you use event handler it attaches events to already generated dom elements as well as dynamically generated elements.

Comment: i already tried that and it's not working. when i try to type on the added row the autocomplete shows on the first row.

Comment: now, everything is not working. idk, what's the problem. thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: Oops.. I forgot to close the single quote of $('.autocomplete')

Comment: try this:
$(document).on("click",".autocomplete",function() {

Comment: yes, i checked the console. nothing is wrong. but it's not working.